# Changing directory to a folder matching a regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, directory, matching

I want to CD into a folder that begins with the word "Patch", followed by several other digits. All I care about is that it begins with the word "Patch"

How can I change my directory using a regex in powershell?

This is what I have at the moment and it doesn't work. Am I on the right track though?

```
$FolderPath = "^Patch[0-9]+$"

cd "C:\Test\" + $FolderPath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put you in the right direction:

Use Get-ChildItem and only get the directories matching your regex, something like:

```
$matchingItem = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test" -Directory | ?{ $_.Name -match $FolderPath } | select -First 1
```

Now you can `cd` to the matching directory.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the regex. Wildcard blobbing will handle that:

```
cd c:\test\patch[0-9]*
```